# how to define a Likelihood function for this case for MLE

Tags: maximum-likelihood, python, likelihood, statsmodels

I am working on a simple algorithm , that takes  social graph as input and for each node, calculates the adoption of a particular behavior based on the number of adopted neighbors. i.e. more the adopted neighbors , more the probability that node adopts the behavior.

So if I know that adoption probability(which I call imitation probability) q = 0.2, and number of neighbors is m, this is how I calculate adoption:

get informed returns 1 = adopted , 0 = non adopted

---

```
def get_informed(m, q):
    """

    :param m: no of active neighbors
    :param q: immitation param (between 0 and 1)
    :return:
    """
    # p = 1 - (1-q)^m
    p = 1 - pow((1 - q), m) # probability of adoption 

    # u is random number between 0 and 1
    u = random.uniform(0, 1)
    if u < p:
        return 1
    return 0
```

Now if I have observed data I need to be able to find q
eg :

```
endog: (value of m) [2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 4, 7, 8]
exog: (adopted/ non adopted) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

How can I find q that maximizes the probability of getting these observations?

I am new to statistics and have been trying to understand MLE (which I think is the way to solve my problem)

I came across two options :

1. using Scipy.stats.optimize
2. using [statsmodel](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/generic_mle.html)

using statsModel seem to provide direct way of using MLE , if I could define loglike function, which is where I am stuck right now.

This is a toy example, That I am trying to work out, to understand how to use statsmodel implementation of MLE

Following is the notebook where I am trying to work out this example.

https://github.com/swatisaoji1/ipy_probit/blob/master/test_probit_cascade.ipynb

Comment: Are you just asking for help w/ the Python code (which would be off topic here), or do you have a statistical question about MLE?

Comment: I need help with defining the log likelihood function, irrespective of whether it is used with python or something else, although I am looking forward to using it with Python so I specifically mentioned the libraries.

Comment: OK, no problem. I got lost in the code discussion.